# @PrePersist EventListener alternative for spring-data-mongo

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-mongodb

I created a `Repository` to  auto increment the id of `@Document` but right now I need to explicitly call the `@Id` setter method to set the new id. 
Is there a way I can do this using listeners like in JPA `@PrePersist`

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository : MongoRepository<User, Long>, UserRepositoryCustom

interface UserRepositoryCustom {
    fun save(user: User): User
}

class UserRepositoryImpl(private val mongoOperations: MongoOperations, private val sequenceRepository: SequenceRepository) : UserRepositoryCustom {

    override fun save(user: User): User {
        // need to call this line for every @Document
        user.id = sequenceRepository.getNextId(User.SEQUENCE_KEY)

        mongoOperations.insert(user)
        return user
    }
}
```

[GitHub Code](https://github.com/atuladhar-aman/spring-data-mongo-crud/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/atuladhar/aman/mongocrud/user/UserRepository.kt#L23)

If I implement my code like this I need to call `sequenceRepository.getNextId(...)` for each and every document before I save it.

In JPA we can use `EventListeners` like `@PrePersist`. Is there `spring-data-mongo` alternative or similar function like to achieve this?

Comment: [Why](https://www.clever-cloud.com/blog/engineering/2015/05/20/why-auto-increment-is-a-terrible-idea/) are you using auto-increments at all?

Answer (score 5):

In Spring data mongo provides event listeners. For example, You can extend `AbstractMongoEventListener` class and override the below method to achieve the PrePersist equivalent,

```
public void onBeforeSave(BeforeSaveEvent<E> event) {
    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
      LOG.debug("onBeforeSave({}, {})", event.getSource(), event.getDBObject());
    }
}
```

Comment: For persistance, you need to use onBeforeConvert